# loadgroovedimones

Tags: java

How do I convert the for loop into a recursive function

```
public static void loadMultiDimArray(String args[]){
    int arrlen = args.length;
    int arrvalue = (int) (Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(arrlen)));

    for (int i= 1; i <  arrlen+1; i++) {
        System.out.print(args[i-1] + "\t");
        if (i == arrvalue) {
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Convert 1d into multi dimensional array:

Input                                                     Output

```
> “A” 

A
```

---

```
> “A”, “B” 

A B
```

---

```
> “A”, “B”, “C” 

A B
C
```

---

```
> “A”, “B”, “C”, “D”  

A B 
C D
```

---

```
> “A”, “B”, “C”, “D”, “E”  

A B C 
D E
```

---

```
> “A”, null, “B”, null, “C”, null, “D” 

A null B 
null C null 
D
```

My code is good on 100% test coverage, but I need to try without loop in order to avoid the complexity. Also, I have a separate test file with the datas that tests this logic

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?  Have you tried writing this recursively?  If so, post your code so we can help you understand where to go with it.

Comment: I need to convert a one dimensional array into multidimensional array without any loops:

Comment: what is the structure of the array? `[1,2,3,4,5,6] => [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]` or something else?

Comment: Input                                       Output

“A”, “B”, “C”                              A B

                                                C   

“A”, “B”, “C”, “D”                     A B 

                                              C D 

“A”, “B”, “C”, “D”, “E”             A B C 

                                             D E

Comment: The loop currently doesn't convert anything, it just prints out values.

Comment: Please don't try to explain your question in comments on it.  Instead, edit your question to make it more clear.

Comment: I am getting the output but I need to try without using any loops

Comment: What is the value of `start`?

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, recursion needs a helper function, especialy if using arrays.
Your recursive function need a termination condition. In this case => end of array.
So the recursive function needs following parameters:

`array originalArray`

`array new2DArray`

`int posInArray`

Knowing this, its realy simple to create a recursive function.

This is not the best way to do it, but i think, you will understand it and can improve it:

```
public static int[][] convertArray(int[] arr) {
    // get size of new arrr
    int newSize = (int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(arr.length));
    // create the new arr
    int[][] newArr = new int[newSize][newSize];

    // call recursive function
    return convertArrayRec(arr, newArr, 0);
}

public static int[][] convertArrayRec(int[] arr, int[][] narr, int pos) {
    // if all done, return the array
    if (pos >= arr.length)
        return narr;

    // if not all done, put the value in new array and increase pos
    narr[pos / narr.length][pos % narr.length] = arr[pos];
    return convertArrayRec(arr, narr, ++pos);
}
```

**EDIT:**
Running this code you should recieve the output, you want. Try it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] in = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 };
    int[][] out = HelloWorld.convertArray(in);
    for (int i = 0; i < out.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < out[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(out[i][j] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The Output will be:

```
1   2   3   4   
5   6   7   8   
9   10  11  12  
13  0   0   0
```

**EDIT 2:**

Here the code, with strings (not intagers) and without any loop^^. The function only print the output, dont return the array.  If you need to return the 2D array, use the code, i have posted here.

http://pastebin.com/5wPJgDSh

Comment: Thanks!, but as I have mentioned, I am supposed to avoid loops

Comment: @Diva - the only reason the loop is there is to show you the output of the array that was returned.

Comment: @Diva there is no loop in the core function, but to print the output, i used a loop. It is also possible to make the output inside the recursive function.

Comment: I tried your code it, the code covers  90.91% of my logic. I have a separate class for my test. I am using Cobertura tool, it highlights the first line (the lines not covered). i.e., the class name is in red.

Comment: i think, its because of the static methods, so the class itself is never used for creating an instance. Making the methods not static and creating a constructor, with the code from main method, should change the coverage to 100%

Answer (score 1):

Simple runnable example

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] tests = new String[][] {
        {"A"},
        {"A", "B"},
        {"A", "B", "C"},
        {"A", "B", "C", "D"},
        {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"},
        {"A", null, "B", null, "C", null, "D"}
    };

    for (String[] test : tests) {
        int arrvalue = (int) (Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(test.length)));
        printRectangle(test, 0, arrvalue);
        System.out.println("---------");
    }

  }

  // recursive "helper" function
  private static void printRectangle(String[] s, int position, final int columns) {
      if (columns <= 0) {
          System.err.println("Not possible!");
          return;
      }
      if (position >= s.length) {
          System.out.println();
          return;
      }

      if (position != 0 && position % columns == 0) {
          System.out.println();
      }

      System.out.print(s[position] + "\t");
      printRectangle(s, position + 1, columns); // recursion here
  }
}
```

---

#### Output

```
A   
---------
A   B   
---------
A   B   
C   
---------
A   B   
C   D   
---------
A   B   C   
D   E   
---------
A   null    B   
null    C   null    
D   
---------
```

Comment: Thank you, it works fine. Need to check the complexity. I appreciate it!

Comment: I worked on this code, the code coverage is only 88%.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/5wPJgDSh   Working in 100% of cases, see my answer to  get a more featured version of this code. This example print only the array, and not returns it (like the code in my answer). I think, its what you want.

Comment: @Diva - Did you pass a negative value to the `columns` parameter? I don't see why it would be less than 100% if you did that.

Comment: @cricket_007 I am not passing negative value

Comment: @Jarlik Stepsto Thanks for your help, your code coverage is 90%

Comment: @Diva please post an array, that is not working

Comment: @Jarlik Stepsto your code covers 100% test, but I am using a tool called cobertura which now says, the percentage of lines covered is 88.89% and it highlights the, public class className{ , in red. Which I don't understand.

Comment: @Diva - If you don't pass a non-positive value (`<= 0`) to `columns`, then the first if-statement of my answer won't be entered, therefore, 100% of the code won't be covered.

Comment: @cricket_007 I tired, it does not cover 100%

Answer (score -1):

First - I only know some Java.  I took a course in Wasshington, D.C. a LOOOOONNNNGGGG time ago. But I know C/C++, Pascal, Perl, PHP, and tons of other useless languages. :-)

Anyway, in order to do recursion all you have to do is to remember that each time you go into the routine - everything that isn't static is wiped clean.  A simple example would be:

```
function a($b)
{
   $b = $b + 1;
   return a($b);
}
```

Now.  You might think the above function (from PHP) would return something but I didn't give it a cut-off point.  (So I didn't put something like

```
   if $b > 10 then return $b;
```

So the above would just give you a memory core dump or stack overflow.  This is the second rule of recursion - always provide a way out of the recursion.

Next.  Never just leave the recursion.  Always unwind it.  This is because each time you call the function over again that information gets stuck onto the stack.  So just like not giving it anyway to get out of the recursion - you will get a memory core dump or stack overflow SOME PLACE ELSE FOR NO APPARENT REASON. But the reason would be you filled up the stack and left it that way.  Always unwind.  Always keep doing returns until you pop out of the recursive routine.

That's it.  Just modify your code so the function calls itself, do your process, and provide a way out of the recursion that does an unwind.

Have fun! :-)

So the full function would be:

```
function a($b=0)
{
 $b = $b + 1;
 if( $b > 10 )then return $b;
 return a($b);
}
```

Hey!  Why the minus one?  I didn't just give him/her the answer because I thought this probably was an assignment.  All I'm doing is showing them how to do recursion so they can adapt their program to be recursive.  :-)

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but I am looking to convert in java.

Comment: @Diva Java is a lot like PHP which is a lot like Perl which is a lot like Basic.  It isn't the CODE that matters - it is the CONCEPT.  Got it?